# Getting error list is not callable

Tags: python

I'm trying to retreive a random card from a deck.

```
import itertools, random
from random import randint
class card:
    __deck = list(itertools.product(range(1,14),['s','h','d','c']))
    def getCard(self):
        randCard = self.__deck(randint(0,52))
        return randcard
card = card()
print card.getCard()
```

This returns: `TypeError: 'list' object is not callable`

Comment: Also, your variable `randcard` that you return is not the same as `randCard`...

Comment: Also, you want `self.__deck[randint(0,51)]` or `self.__deck[randrange(52)]`. Or even better `choice(self.__deck)`.

Comment: And you can't have a variable `card` for your card instance because that clobbers your `card` class. You should use PEP-8 naming conventions and call the class `Card`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self.__deck(randint(0,52))` attempts to *call* the list `self.__deck`, which is of course not callable.

To access an element of a list, use this:

```
self.__deck[randint(0,52)]
```

Assuming that `return randcard` is a typo as it should actually be `return randCard`.

Comment: Thank you so much, I also had to remove the randcard variable and return the statement directly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the line `randCard = self.__deck(randint(0,52))`

What you have done is use parentheses instead of square brackets:

```
randCard = self.__deck(randint(0,52))
\/
randCard = self.__deck[randint(0,52)]
```

You have also got a lower case inside the second `randCard` which I have fixed for you in the following code.
New code:

```
import itertools, random
from random import randint
class card:
    __deck = list(itertools.product(range(1,14),['s','h','d','c']))
    def getCard(self):
        randCard = self.__deck[randint(0,51)] # This line was creating the error. Also randint will return a value from 0 to 52 included so its a good idea to change it to randint(0, 51)
        return randCard
card = card()
print card.getCard()
```

Square brackets are used for accessing an array index whereas parentheses are used to call a function, that's why the error is saying you are trying to call a list.